# How to overline only part of the text in subscript format

Tags: math-mode

I can format `h_y` using the command `$\overline{h_y}$`, but I want to type `h_y,max` where `y,max` is subscript but the horizontal line of overline only cover `h_y`.

Thank you

Comment: Probably not ideal, but what about `$\overline{h_y}{}_{,max}$`?

Comment: Can you explain what the notation should mean?  I would suspect something like `$(\overline{h_y})_{\max}$` would be more appropriate, but the context matters.

Answer (score 4):

Though I think this notation might confuse the reader, here is a solution which makes the `max` part have zero width by using `\mathrlap`. The following `\hphantom` puts (nearly) the same amount of space back in.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
$\overline{h_{y,\mathrm{max}}} = 1$
\medskip

$\overline{h_{y\mathrlap{,\mathrm{max}}}}_{\hphantom{,\mathrm{max}}} = 1$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

$\overline{h_{y\mathrlap{,\max}}}$ \qquad foo

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why `\qquad`? That's arbitrary.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest strategy is to add an overline with the desired width (but occupying no horizontal space) and then typeset the symbol to be partially overlined.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\partialoverline}[1]{%
  \mathrlap{\overline{\phantom{#1}}}%
}

\begin{document}

$\partialoverline{h_y}h_{y,\max}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great short macro code.

Answer (score 1):

My proposal is to use a spartan macro called `\oversize`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\newcommand{\oversize}[1]{\mkern-1.5mu\overline{\mkern-1.5mu#1\mkern-28mu}\mkern30mu}
\begin{document}
$\oversize{h_{y,\mathrm{max}}}= 1$
\end{document}
```

Changhing the values of two `\mkern` of `\overline{\mkern0mu#1\mkern-10mu}` you can increase the lenght of `\overline`. The last `\mkern10mu` it is only to bring closer to the code equality and 1.
See the example below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
    \newcommand{\oversize}[1]{\mkern-1.5mu\overline{\mkern0mu#1\mkern-10mu}\mkern10mu}
    \begin{document}
    $\oversize{h_{y,\mathrm{max}}}= 1$
    \end{document}
```